# Ошибка в parrot os

Tags: linux, debian, parrot-os

E: Репозиторий «http://deb.debian.org/debian experemintal Release» не содержит файла Release. N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён. N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).

Как это исравить?
объясните пожалуйста на языке для новичков в линукс

Comment: Смотрю релиз файл на месте http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/experimental/

Answer (score 2):

9 часов назад релиз файл для этой репы обновляли. Похоже Вы попали в момент обновления. Попробуйте ещё раз и все получится.

Релиз файл на месте http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/experimental/

Проверьте строчку в /etc/apt/sources.list*

должно быть

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experemintal contrib main non-free-firmware non-free
```